# Quelle est la manière correcte d'utiliser le futur ?

Tags: futur

Premièrement, pardon pour de possibles erreurs, j'apprends le français depuis mercredi dernier.

Quand je veux utiliser le futur, quelle est la manière correcte de le faire ?

Par exemple:

> Nous pouvons nous rencontrer quand tu peux.

ou

> Nous pouvons nous rencontrer quand tu pouvoir.

Comment: Tu veux peut-être parler de [futur](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicatif_futur_simple_en_fran%C3%A7ais) et pas de [conditionnel](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditionnel). Que veux-tu dire par combiner ? (ce n'est certainement pas le verbe que tu cherches, tu peux le donner dans un autre langue...)

Comment: Probablement _se rencontrer_ ?

Comment: pardon! @Frank est correct. Le correct mot est rencontrer! Et merci Laure, je suis en train de parler du futur. Pardon pour la confusion.

Comment: Pour commencer, on ne dit pas: quelle est la manière correcte. On dit: comment utilise-t-on le futur correctement? Vote to close, too broad.

Comment: @Lambie, pardon, Je suis un débutant. Je n'ai voulu pas être vague. La question a fait répondu. Pouvez vous expliquer por moi pourquoi on ne dit pas "quelle est la manière correcte?"
Merci par la attention.

Comment: Il y des sites entiers sur l'internet pour apprendre l'utilisation du futur en français. La question est trop générale à mon avis. Avant d'apprendre le futur, il vaut mieux apprendre comment utiliser les pronoms me, moi, te, toi, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je dirais:

> Nous pourrons nous rencontrer quand tu pourras.

Le verbe *se rencontrer* est réflexif, le *nous* est nécessaire. Pour le futur du verbe *pouvoir* (infinitif), c'est *tu pourras*.

Dans une conversation plus familière, on dirait probablement:

> On se rencontre quand tu peux.

ou:

> On se rencontre dès que tu peux.

qui peut aussi être utilisé comme une question avec la bonne intonation (ascendante).

En déviant un peu plus, la formule suivante est très courante, mais seulement en conversation très familière:

> On se rencontre à la première occase.

(*occase* étant un mot d'argot pour *occasion*).

Il y d'autres variantes en langue parlée (plus ou moins correctes, mais qu'on entend):

> Nous pouvons nous rencontrer quand tu peux.
>
> Nous pourrons nous rencontrer quand tu peux.

Comment: merci beaucoup. Ces't la response que j'ai cherché.

Comment: Agreed about "pourrons" especially -- the "futur" is only implied in the other examples, after all. :)